# Can't Install iOS SDK on MeteorJS

Tags: meteor

I'm following instructions on https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile.

Whenever I try (from my app folder)

```
meteor install-sdk ios
```

It says, "Please follow the instructions here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Development-Install:-iOS-on-Mac"

Which I've done. I've tried uninstalling XCode and installing again, I've tried `sudo xcodebuild -license` but no luck.

What gives! Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a silly problem, that command doesn't do anything at all. It's kinda misleading since it has the word "install". Therefore I ignored it, and just used:

```
meteor add-platform ios
meteor run ios
```

And everything is gold.